# Liquid conductors and conservation

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, molecular-dynamics, thermoelectricity

Would gas or liquid conductors cost less than metal and are they more efficient conductor? Is there a material that would contain a magnetic field and would it increase conductivity? If so,  This would be good to conduct electricity over large distances.[image]?

Would ionized matter stay ionized if sealed?

Comment: This question is a little vague. Do you have in mind a particular application or types of conductors? In general, a liquid or gas has to be contained. An ionized gas or liquid has to be kept ionized. These would make life more expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good conductors are materials providing a lot of efficient electric charge transporters. electrons and ions are two kinds of them. But electron are light and in stable phase in metal, while ions in fluids are heavy, slow, and need the fluid to be there, contained, not changed too much in partial densities of components, and this for a very long time if it's more than for an experiment. In addition in case of important power the metal can accept some heating, while the liquid (and/or containment) is likely to easily degenerate with heat.

Permanent ionized gas needs energy and devices to keep ionized. Discharge tube requires huge tension and have to handle temperature/pressure change, but it's basically the neon tube.

To summarize, electrons are lovely and difficult to beat :-)

Comment: Not to mention that "conductive" ions are by definition, "not in the ground state". This gives rise to a lot more scattering pathways (resistance).